# Is there any way can let greenDAO support android data-binding now?

Tags: android, greendao, android-databinding, greendao-generator

When you use [greenDAO](https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO) library, you need to use **greendao-generator** to generate relevant POJO and XXXDAO, DAOSession, DAOMaster class. Just like this POJO class here: [Note.java](https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO/blob/master/DaoExample%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fde%2Fgreenrobot%2Fdaoexample%2FNote.java)

```
// THIS CODE IS GENERATED BY greenDAO, DO NOT EDIT. Enable "keep" sections if you want to edit. 
/**
 * Entity mapped to table "NOTE".
 */
public class Note {

    private Long id;
    /** Not-null value. */
    private String text;
    private String comment;
    private java.util.Date date;

    public Note() {
    }

    public Note(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Note(Long id, String text, String comment, java.util.Date date) {
        this.id = id;
        this.text = text;
        this.comment = comment;
        this.date = date;
    }

    // Getter and setter...

}
```

And each time you change your model, this code need to be regenerated.

[Android data-binding](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/tools/data-binding/guide.html) can be used by giving your data objects the ability to notify when data changes.But before that, you need to modify your POJO class.There are different data change notification mechanisms: [Data Objects](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/tools/data-binding/guide.html#data_objects)

1.implementing the `Observable` interface, assigning a `Bindable` annotation and call `notifyPropertyChanged()` method in setter.

```
private static class User extends BaseObservable {
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;
   @Bindable
   public String getFirstName() {
       return this.firstName;
   }
   @Bindable
   public String getLastName() {
       return this.lastName;
   }
   public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
       this.firstName = firstName;
       notifyPropertyChanged(BR.firstName);
   }
   public void setLastName(String lastName) {
       this.lastName = lastName;
       notifyPropertyChanged(BR.lastName);
   }
}
```

2.Use ObservableFields or Observable Collections:

```
private static class User {
   public final ObservableField<String> firstName =
       new ObservableField<>();
   public final ObservableField<String> lastName =
       new ObservableField<>();
   public final ObservableInt age = new ObservableInt();
}
```

So, if we want to use **greenDAO** and **Android data-binding** together, we need to modify the automatically generated file manually? I believe this is a very large amount of work if your project is large. Or Is there any elegant way can let greenDAO support android data-binding now?

Looking forward to your reply! Thanks!